# How to use methods in a class from a package I've created

Tags: java, methods, package

i'm making a calculator program in java. I created a package calculator which has 4 classes. The package takes in an equation and finds its result (this program works). Now I want to use this logic for a graphic calculator so I wrote

```
package calculator;
```

at the top of each class (made sure it was the first line in each class). I then wrote

```
import calculator.JCalc;
```

in my class with the graphic calculator the class is also called Calculator (JCalc is the class with all the logic for performing the calculations). In my class Calculator id like to perform the method findResult when the user hits the "=" button but I'm not sure how to access this method inside the class Calculator can someone please tell me how I can do this.

```
private String find_result(String equation) {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Marc provided should work providing the method you want to call within the Calculator Class is declared as public:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator(); 
System.out.println(calc.find_result("3+3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a Calculator object you can call from...

Calculator calc = new Calculator();
calc.(some methods)

Comment: Thanks for answering, just tried that and it didn't work I also tried writing calculator with lowercase 'c's because I wrote the name of the package in lower case and thought thats what you were trying to refer to but that also didn't work

Comment: when I write Calculator (capital C like the way you wrote it) I get the error on my method find_result and it says the method find_result(String) is undefined for the type Calculator. When i write calculator calc = new calculator.JCalc(); I get the error on that statement and it says calculator cannot be resolved to a type. Btw which did you mean

Comment: What @Marc provided should work providing the method you want to call within that class is declared as **public** :  `Calculator calc = new Calculator(); System.out.println(calc.find_result("3+3"));`

Comment: What is the .JCalc() for? You only need to make a object by calling the constructor just like @DevilsHnd :) the .JCalc() method should by called on the calc object after you constructed it :)

Comment: yah but wouldn't the constructor be from the package calculator and not from the class Calculator. Not really understanding how "new Calculator" will allow me to use methods from the package calculator

Answer (score 0):

Like this my friend :)

```
package calculator; 
import calculator.JCalc; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOMECLASSNAME()
{ 
   Calculator calc = new Calculator();
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String myEquation = SOME EQUALTION
       printResult(myEquation);
   }

   public void printResult(String myEquation)
   {
      if (scanner.equals("=")) 
         System.out.println(calc.find_result(myEquation))
      else printResult(); // recalls the method until "=" is typed.
   }   
}
```

Comment: hey really appreciate the help but its still not working my code is very long so not gonna send it but u think there are any other weird reasons why it might not be working

Comment: and would SOMECLASSNAME() be Calculator in my case

Comment: wow sorry brow, I just now understood your problem... you dont need to import your class you need to make a object of that class you want to reach. like before but instead of 'Calculator calc = new Calculator();' because that is the your main class right? write 'JCalc calc = new JCalc();' after this you should be able to call the methods from your class trough your 'calc' object :)

Comment: No problem remember to hit the answered button :)